# Quarkus - Azrue Function - Included JAR needed?

Tags: azure-functions, quarkus

When I package our Quarkus app to an Azure Function than I can see a JAR with the name 'quarkus-ide-launcher-[quarkus version].jar'. This JAR is about 13 MB in size but is it needed when the app is deployed on Azure?

quarkus-ide-launcher-[quarkus version].jar' file:-

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried running and deploying Quarkus Function app with JAR file and it got deployed successfully.

**Local:-**

[image]

[image]

I deployed the Function app with JAR file by running this command and the deployment was successful:-

**Command:-**

```bash
./mvnw clean package azure-functions:deploy
```

**Portal:-**

[image]

[image]

Now, ***I deleted the quarkus-ide-launcher-3.1.2.Final file and tried the deployment again, The Deployment was successful. Thus you can delete the JAR file and run your Azure Quarkus Function app deployment.***

[image]

I changed the function app name in pom.xml and kept the rest of the resource group and other parameters as it is to deploy this Function in the same resource group, Refer below:-

[image]

[image]

In order to run your Function Trigger from Portal add the below CORS setting and allow- **https://portal.azure.com**

[image]

***Function Trigger deployed without JAR file ran successfully,*** Like below:-

[image]

Comment: That's good to know. Our setup of deploying is a little bit different due to our employers way of working but I can see if I can remove the JAR before the app is deployed on Azure. Every little bit of memory we can reduce is a gain :-)